# Stop scroll of parent (NestedScrollview) When scrolling Child(RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I need behavior similar to this implementation But NestedScrollView would be the parent and RecyclerView would be the child of would NestedScrollView .

Eg: https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/scrollable-nestedscrollviews-inside-recyclerview-ca65050d828a

I am not sure whether it can be achieved.Tried disabling the of parent(NSV) while child(RV)is scrolling But scroll on child scrolls the entire view including parent.

Comment: did you get the answer as per medium it can achievable, can you please share some code

Answer (score 3):

I'v implemented [Marc Knaup](https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/scrollable-nestedscrollviews-inside-recyclerview-ca65050d828a) solution and all works correct event if `NestedScrollView` would be the parent and the result was shown below

[image]

btw, i put what i'v done

**CustomRecycleView**

```
package com.example.nested_scroll_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.core.view.NestedScrollingParent;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class CustomRecycleView extends RecyclerView implements NestedScrollingParent {
    private View nestedScrollTarget = null;
    private boolean nestedScrollTargetIsBeingDragged = false;
    private boolean nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false;
    private boolean skipsTouchInterception = false;


    public CustomRecycleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomRecycleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomRecycleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        boolean temporarilySkipsInterception = nestedScrollTarget != null;
        if (temporarilySkipsInterception) {
            // If a descendent view is scrolling we set a flag to temporarily skip our onInterceptTouchEvent implementation
            skipsTouchInterception = true;
        }

        // First dispatch, potentially skipping our onInterceptTouchEvent
        boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

        if (temporarilySkipsInterception) {
            skipsTouchInterception = false;

            // If the first dispatch yielded no result or we noticed that the descendent view is unable to scroll in the
            // direction the user is scrolling, we dispatch once more but without skipping our onInterceptTouchEvent.
            // Note that RecyclerView automatically cancels active touches of all its descendents once it starts scrolling
            // so we don't have to do that.
            if (!handled || nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll) {
                handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        }

        return handled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return !skipsTouchInterception && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        if (dyConsumed != 0) {
            // The descendent was actually scrolled, so we won't bother it any longer.
            // It will receive all future events until it finished scrolling.
            nestedScrollTargetIsBeingDragged = true;
            nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false;
        } else if (dyConsumed == 0 && dyUnconsumed != 0) {
            // The descendent tried scrolling in response to touch movements but was not able to do so.
            // We remember that in order to allow RecyclerView to take over scrolling.
            nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = true;
            if (target.getParent() != null)
                target.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScrollAccepted(View child, View target, int axes) {
        if (axes != 0 && View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0) {
            // A descendent started scrolling, so we'll observe it.
            nestedScrollTarget = target;
            nestedScrollTargetIsBeingDragged = false;
            nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false;
        }

        super.onNestedScrollAccepted(child, target, axes);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return nestedScrollAxes != 0 && View.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopNestedScroll(View child) {
        nestedScrollTarget = null;
        nestedScrollTargetIsBeingDragged = false;
        nestedScrollTargetWasUnableToScroll = false;
    }
}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Top Section"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.example.nested_scroll_test.CustomRecycleView
                android:id="@+id/rw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </com.example.nested_scroll_test.CustomRecycleView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Bottom Section"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**RecycleViewItem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nsw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="#CCCC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

post entire thing what you have tried so far.

your xml should be ,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

              <View > <!-- upper content -->

              <!-- set recycler view with with wrap_content -->
              <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
      </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

set scrolling behaviour inside onCreateView() / onCreate() method.
requires Api 21+ .

```
    RecyclerView v = (RecyclerView) findViewById(...);
    v.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                   or 
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"  // inside recycler view in xml file
```

Comment: scrolling behaviour mentioned in this https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/scrollable-nestedscrollviews-inside-recyclerview-ca65050d828a cannot be achieved by using overscroll mode .

Comment: this is not a solution because android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" freeze recycleview.

Answer (score 0):

@Rockin use overscrollmode bro:)

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="always"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:orientation="vertical">


       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView                
           android:id="@+id/activity_insight_recyclerview_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
          app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/raw_insight" />
```

Comment: scrolling behaviour mentioned in this https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/scrollable-nestedscrollviews-inside-recyclerview-ca65050d828a cannot be achieved by using overscroll mode .

Comment: @Rockin you have to give android:layout_height="match_parent" and it's defiantly work i am using this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is demo for what you want look, In **MainActivity.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_seller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200sp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_seller1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200sp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/product_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_seller2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200sp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_seller3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200sp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/background"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your **MainActivity.java** class `onCreate` method:

```
   RecyclerView bestRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.product_list);
   GridLayoutManager mGrid = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
   bestRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGrid);
   bestRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   bestRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
   // Create ProductAdapter for  RecyclerView data
   ProductAdapter mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(MainActivity4.this,getProductTestData());
   bestRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

[image]

I hope It'll help you...!

Comment: Have you find your answers or need a help?

Comment: Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

In general simple trick works for me. When attaching OnTouchListener to child View, in onTouch() just disable touch interrupts. Something like this:

```
        RecyclerView rv = findViewById(...);
        rv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            ...
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try subclass the RV and override onInterceptTouchEvent?

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

    when (event!!.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {


        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

            // WE INTERACT WITH THIS RV. PREVENT PARENT TO INTERCEPT 
            parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) 

        }


        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {

            // THIS SEEMS LIKE IT WILL HAVE "DEFAULT" BEHAVIOUR BUT SINCE WE CURRENTLY DRAGGING THE RV THEN IT WONT SCROLL THE PARENT  
            parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)

        }

    }

    return false
}
```